# android webview goes more than full width for responsive sites

Tags: android, css, webview

I have a simple webview:

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

Which is called like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com");
    }
```

The problem is that the site I am trying to render doesn't go into responsive mode.  The width goes beyond the screen causing me to scroll.

I have tried widths including: fill_parent, match_parent, and wrap_content and none of them work.

What can I do to make the webpage render responsive, staying in the confines of the screen without scrolling horizontally?

Comment: Does the webpage resize correctly in a mobile browser?  You may need to set the `<viewport>` in your HTML.  Your WebView is indeed filling the screen, but the content _within_ it is too wide for the page.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are missing a couple of setup calls that make WebView to render more like a mobile browser:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

Optionally, you can also enable pinch-zooming:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

And as @Hylianpuffball correctly noted, your website should be ideally using `<viewport>` tag for controlling its presentation.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the most way to have the webview render properly by using setScale:

```
webView.setInitialScale((int) (getScale());
```

were getScale method caluclates the screen size using this alogrithm:

metrics.density*10

Then you can use a factor of the scale by dividing by a value less than 1.5 to fine tune it

Comment: why `getScale()` deprecated? @TimeForCode

Answer (score 0):

The error is displayed in the line

webView.setInitialScale((int) (getScale());

Comment: (((The problem is that the site I am trying to render doesn't go into responsive mode. The width goes beyond the screen causing me to scroll.

I have tried widths including: fill_parent, match_parent, and wrap_content and none of them work.

What can I do to make the webpage render responsive, staying in the confines of the screen without scrolling horizontally?  ))))

Comment: I added these codes
  webView.getSettings (). setUseWideViewPort (true);
         webView.getSettings (). setLoadWithOverviewMode (true);

         webView.getSettings (). setSupportZoom (true);
         webView.getSettings (). setBuiltInZoomControls (true);
         webView.getSettings (). setDisplayZoomControls (true);

Comment: The problem has now been fixed. I just want to delete the side spaces